# Geometric structures which always exist

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

It is well known fact that Riemannian metric always exist on any manifold. Another way to say that is that any manifold always admit $O(n)$ structure i.e. $O(n)$ reduction of structure group of frame bundle $L(M)$.

One way to see that (next to the classical argument with partition of unity) is that $Gl(n)/O(n)$ is contactible, existance of a $G$ structure is equivalent to the existance of section of a fibre bundle $L(M)/G$ and fibre bundles with contractible fibre always possess one.

**My questions are:**

$\bullet$ What are another closed subgroups $G \subset Gl(n)$ with $Gl(n)/G$ contractible ?

$\bullet$ What are another closed subgroups $G \subset Gl(n)$ such that any manifold admits $G$ structure?

Answer (score 1):

For compact case, there is essentially one such subgroup up to conjugation, which is $O(n)$. Indeed, one can apply Corollary 1.4 in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-012-0389-8), which says that for a compact subgroup $H$ in an almost connected locally compact group $G$, $G/H$ is contractible if and only if $H$ is maximal compact. In the case $G = GL(n,\mathbb R)$ they are conjugate of $O(n)$.

Comment: I find your answear helpfoul, yet if I would ask 6 years ago, then we wouldn't know even that partial answear (paper is from 2011) ?

Comment: Good comment. My answer is an overkill I suppose. I guess one can check directly the above theorem for $GL(n, \mathbb R)$. @J.E.M.S